# Radio button selection in JSP page

Tags: authentication, jsp, radio-button

I need a help from you guys... I'm doing my final year project in that login page with three kinds of login i.e., admin , employee and project manager in that if I click on admin radio button and login with that it should go to admin JSP page and the corresponding rest too . In that what should I do ?

```
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>INDICES TECHNO IT PARK</title>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <style>

        td{

            padding: 20px;

        }

        div{

            width:"90";

            border:10px black;

            border-radius:20px;

            background-color: sandybrown;

        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div align = center>

<h1><b><font color="Brown" size="12" style="font-family: cursive"> WELCOME TO INDICES TECHNO IT PARK!</font></b></h1>

<h1><b><font color="Sky Blue" size="8" style="font-family: cursive"> LOGIN FORM</font></b></h1>

<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">

<table>

<tr>

<td width="30%"><b><font size="3" style="font-family: cursive">SELECT_USER</font></b></td>

<td width="20%"><b><font color="black" size="3" style="font-family: cursive"><input type="radio" name="SELECT_USER" value="Admin.jsp">Admin</font></b></td>

<td width="25%"><b><font color="black" size="3" style="font-family: cursive"><input type="radio" name="SELECT_USER" value="Employee.jsp">Employee</font></b></td>

<td width="50%"><b><font color="black" size="3" style="font-family: cursive"><input type="radio" name="SELECT_USER" value="Project_Manager.jsp">Project_Manager</font></b></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><b><font size="3" style="font-family:cursive">EMPLOYEE NAME</font></b> </td>

<td><b><font style="font family:cursive"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Employee name"placeholder="Employee name"/></font></b></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><b><font size="3" style="font-family:cursive">EMPLOYEE ID</font></b> </td>

<td><b><font style="font family:cursive"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Employee ID"placeholder="Employee ID"/></font></b></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><b><font size="3" style="font-family:cursive">EMAIL ID</font></b> </td>

<td><b><font style="font family:cursive"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email id"placeholder="Employee id"/></font></b></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><b><font size="3" style="font-family:cursive">PASSWORD</font></b> </td>

<td><b><font style="font family:cursive"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Password"placeholder="Password"/></font></b></td>

</tr>

<tr><td><b><font size="3"><font color="Black" size="10" style="font-family: cursive"><input class="btn btn-success" type="SUBMIT" value="LOGIN"/></font></font></b></td>

<td><b><font size="3"><font color="Black" size="10" style="font-family: cursive"><input class="btn btn-success" type="RESET" value="RESET"/></font></font></b></td>

</table>

</form>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem do you have? If you submit the form to the server it should handle the value of selection and redirect to the corresponding page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of jquery to get Selected Radio field value and than redirect to corresponding JSP here is the updated code per your requirement .

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>INDICES TECHNO IT PARK</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <style>
          td{
          padding: 20px;
          }
          div{
          width:"90";
          border:10px black;
          border-radius:20px;
          background-color: sandybrown;
          }
       </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          function onSubmit(){
          if($("input[type='radio'].radioBtnClass").is(':checked')) {
              var card_type = $("input[type='radio'].radioBtnClass:checked").val();
              alert(card_type);
            window.location.href = card_type;
          
          }
          }
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div align = center>
          <h1><b><font color="Brown" size="12" style="font-family: cursive"> WELCOME TO INDICES TECHNO IT PARK!</font></b></h1>
          <h1><b><font color="Sky Blue" size="8" style="font-family: cursive"> LOGIN FORM</font></b></h1>
          <table>
             <tr>
                <td width="30%"><b><font size="3" style="font-family: cursive">SELECT_USER</font></b></td>
                <td width="20%"><b><font color="black" size="3" style="font-family: cursive"><input type="radio" class="radioBtnClass" name="SELECT_USER" value="Admin.jsp">Admin</font></b></td>
                <td width="25%"><b><font color="black" size="3" style="font-family: cursive"><input type="radio" class="radioBtnClass" name="SELECT_USER" value="Employee.jsp">Employee</font></b></td>
                <td width="50%"><b><font color="black" size="3" style="font-family: cursive"><input type="radio" class="radioBtnClass" name="SELECT_USER" value="Project_Manager.jsp">Project_Manager</font></b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><b><font size="3" style="font-family:cursive">EMPLOYEE NAME</font></b> </td>
                <td><b><font style="font family:cursive"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Employee name"placeholder="Employee name"/></font></b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><b><font size="3" style="font-family:cursive">EMPLOYEE ID</font></b> </td>
                <td><b><font style="font family:cursive"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Employee ID"placeholder="Employee ID"/></font></b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><b><font size="3" style="font-family:cursive">EMAIL ID</font></b> </td>
                <td><b><font style="font family:cursive"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email id"placeholder="Employee id"/></font></b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><b><font size="3" style="font-family:cursive">PASSWORD</font></b> </td>
                <td><b><font style="font family:cursive"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Password"placeholder="Password"/></font></b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><b><font size="3"><font color="Black" size="10" style="font-family: cursive"><input class="btn btn-success" type="SUBMIT" value="LOGIN" onClick="onSubmit()"/></font></font></b></td>
                <td><b><font size="3"><font color="Black" size="10" style="font-family: cursive"><input class="btn btn-success" type="RESET" value="RESET"/></font></font></b></td>
          </table>
       </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Hope this helps .